# jquery datepicker change position dynamically

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I use several datepickers on my page and in some cases i hide a div with one of them. After that the position of the other datepickers is not correct anymore, they are way above the input. I think that is because the place is determined on initialisation, because if i show the div again the position is correct.

But how to make the position that it changes if an other datepicker (div) hides?

Comment: You could use .css('visibility','hidden') instead of .hide() which uses 'display', 'none'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps set the position in the `beforeShow` event:

```
$(".is-datepicker").datepicker("option", "beforeShow", function(input, inst){
   $(inst.dpDiv).position({
      my: "left top",
      at: "left bottom",
      of: $(input)
 });
```

`position()` was added in version 1.8 http://api.jqueryui.com/position/

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4L6EK/)

Comment: Nope, does not work. In Firefox there is no problem i discover now. So it's only IE...

Comment: You didn't try it without replacing `.is-datepicker` with a valid selector did you?

Comment: I did, and what happend is that my input shifted down and the datepicker stil is way above the input

Comment: Yeah it took a little fiddling. Code updated and I added a fiddle. I don't use IE if I can help it and the position call is not needed at all, but it might help.

Comment: You put me in the right way, this is it wat i place in the beforeshow:

Comment: function legen_array(input, inst) {
    // Altijd boven input tonen
          setTimeout(function() {
              inst.dpDiv.position({
                  my: 'left bottom',
                  at: 'left top',
                  collision: 'none',
                  of: input
              });
          }, 1);

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer because the accepted answer did not work for me because I am using 1.7 and maybe someone else will find this useful.

Can be done by using _checkOffset method to alter as needed

```
$.datepicker._checkOffset_original = $.datepicker._checkOffset;
$.datepicker._checkOffset = function(inst, offset, isFixed) {
    var offset = $.datepicker._checkOffset_original(inst, offset, isFixed);
    var alterOffset = this._get(inst, 'alterOffset');
    if (alterOffset)
        return alterOffset.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null), [offset]);  // trigger custom callback
        return offset;
    }
```

and setting on the datepicker the wanted callback

```
$('#id').datepicker('option', 'alterOffset', function(offset){
    //change offset here
    return offset;
});
```