# Positioning of JqueryUI datepicker: how to set its position relative to where it would automatically show up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, datepicker

I have a search page with a filter box on it. In this box are two date filters, Before and After. Each date filter uses the jquery ui-datepicker. The first one looks like this:

[image]

The second one looks like this:

[image]

I need the calendar for the Before Date box (image 2) to show up in the same place as the After Date box (image 1). I don't think I can hardcode the position for the second calendar though, because while that might work on my computer, wider or smaller screens would likely have it in the wrong place. I also can't set it to a relative value, because its position is already set using absolute value. How can I make the second calendar show up, say 200px to the left of where it would automatically show up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I initially thought you would need to wire into a 'onshow' event, so following that train of thought, I found this SO question: [How to change jquery ui datepicker position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131465/how-to-change-jquery-ui-datepicker-position)

In the event handler shown in the sample below from that post, you can then set the position correctly, ie. relative to the other control.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            inst.dpDiv.css({
                top: 100,
                left: 200
            });
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I used [atom.gregg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/957388/atom-gregg)'s answer to come up with the solution:

```
$("#beforedate").datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var offsets = $("#afterdate").offset();
            var top = offsets.top + 25;
            inst.dpDiv.css({
                top: top,
                left: offsets.left,
            });
        });
    }
});
```